# Subqueries and joining - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: mysql

I'm a new code having trouble getting a subquery to work with the main query data.  Essentially I want to count how many PCs are HP PCs from the results.  When I run it I get the error: The multi-part identifier "dbo.softwareapplications.softwareid" could not be bound.

```
select distinct appname, version, linkid,
(select count(make) as totalhp from dbo.workstations where make = 'Hewlett-Packard' and linkdid = t1.linkid)as totalhp
from dbo.softwareapplications as t1
join dbo.assignments on dbo.softwareapplications.softwareid = dbo.IQCSassignments.softwareid
join dbo.workstations on dbo.assignments.wsid = dbo.workstations.wsid
group by assetdescription, version, linkid, totalhp
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that's the identifier in the error message? The one that looks wrong is `dbo.IQCassignments.softwareid`, because you don't mention that table in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: Your query seems to have been cut off -- where is the matching parenthesis, and the `FROM` clause of the main query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've aliased the "dbo.softwareapplications" table as `t1`, that's how you have to refer to it in subsequent clauses:

```
join dbo.assignments on t1.softwareid = dbo.IQCSassignments.softwareid
```

(Or alternatively, remove the "as t1" alias and the other reference to it.)

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely late on a friday, I thought I tried that but of course I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alias you created :  t1.softwareid instead of dbo.softwareapplications.softwareid

Comment: IQCSassignments table doesnt exist in the from clause... you cannot use it on a join operator.